# How do i declare the active Microsoft project in .vb

Tags: vb.net, office-interop, ms-project

I am attempting to connect Microsoft Project files from my VB code in Visual Studio. I know that when using VBA you can simply use the `ActiveProject` resource. VB has a different syntax. What would I need to do to find the active project in VB?

Typically VBA code would look like

```vb
Dim prj as Project
set prj = ActiveProject
```

Comment: The VBA code is inside the project. The VB.NET code is outside of any projects, hence it does not have an active project. See e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/walkthrough-office-programming for a starting point.

Comment: There's a "StartUp project" setting, though. I doubt that it's what you want, but just in case: Open the solution explorer; right click on the project; "Set as StartUp project".

Answer (score 0):

The MS Project [Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application) object will have an [ActiveProject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.activeproject) object regardless of whether you are referencing that object in VBA or .net. The vb.net equivalent is:

```
Dim prj As MSProject.Project = ProjApp.ActiveProject
```

Which presumes this has been previously declared and set:

```
Dim ProjApp As MSProject.Application
```